# Intellij run JSP page option disappear when edit web.xml

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, intellij-idea

First Picture, Option to run JSP page still appear if not set any config in web.xml

[image]

Second Picture, Option to run JSP page disappear when do config in web.xml

[image]

What happen and how can I solved this problem. It's difficult to test each JSP page without this option. Otherwise, I have to start from index.jsp then navigate to particular page or typing URL manually which is not convenience.

Thank you

Comment: We can't reproduce this issue. Please contact JetBrains support with more details (sample project, logs).